# Strength Pareto Evolutionary Algorithm (SPEA 3)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

I am working on optimization using evolutionary algorithm, specifically SPEA-II. I was curious if there is any algorithm named SPEA-III. I tried googling but I could only find a proposed modification of the SPEA-II using [reference search direction](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7886269/). Is it same as SPEA-III, in case of NSGA-III, this is the probably only difference from NSGA-II.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the reason for down voting. I am fixed and do not find any answer to this issue except guessing that the proposed modification is actually being dubbed as SPEA-III.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able find a reference paper on SPEA3, the authors have proposed what they called a generalization of SPEA2 algorithm and name it as [SPEA3](http://www.atlantis-press.com/php/download_paper.php?id=23539).